# Some way to check if the stores is online

Tags: magento, host

I would like to know if there is some way or some extension to use in magento to warning me when my store gets offline for some problem in the host, for some reason is going offline to much the stores.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with previous comments.

The alternative is you invest in;

monitoring tools;
- Pingdom
- ismysiteup.com

application monitoring tools;
- New Relic
- Compuware

The Application Monitoring Tools like new relic are cost effective and give you great insight into not only outages with the applications (apache, MySQL) but also give you insight into how your users are transacting on the site (is it a positive experience for customers).

I'm commenting from the perspective of a Service provider (ultraserve.com.au) and it is up to the provider to supply a notification platform to notify when a system goes offline.

Happy days,

Bruce

Answer (score 0):

If your server will go offline, or apache server will go offline no extension will help you. You could ask your hosting company about this. Sometimes they have those functionalities. So for example when server is down it sends an e-mail to some specific address or even a sms message to your phone.

For apache or mysql fails you would need some test program to check for every 5 mins or 1 min if everything is OK. But this is not done in magento extension, but rather some separate script in python, perl, c++ or any other language that will work on your server.

Comment: You need an external program that tries to access a web page on your server. No access = server down. Pingdom offers such a service. If the server's down, it won't be able to notify you.

Comment: Thank you, i going to test this pingdom !